# in perl, how can I extract a subarray which already exists inside an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl

`@BIG` is an array of arrays. It has subarray 0, subarray 1, etc. I would like to choose any of the subarrays, specify it only by its index, and copy or assign its exact value, including its structure, to `my @extracted_subarray`, without changing `@BIG`.

The code below creates and prints an example of `@BIG`. Then the last line, using `pop`, manages to assign the value of the 2nd (index 1) subarray to `my @extracted_subarray`. This is not what I want, because

1. it only gets the last subarray of `@BIG`, whereas I want to specify any arbitrary existing subarray by its index.
2. it removes the subarray from `@BIG`, whereas I want to leave `@BIG` unmolested.

Certainly there must be a straightforward way to do this. Because I have coded a lot in `R` ([r-project.org](https://r-project.org)), I think of this as a very basic task. But "extract subarray from array of arrays" does not seem to be the right search term. It brings up solutions to more complicated problems than this one.

The two blocks inside `{...}`
raised questions in some individuals reading this post. Thus, an explanation. My practical application will not have hard-coded data elements like that. I will be iterating through a text file with individual lines for the individual elements of the array, and building the array from the text file.

In particular, a line that begins with `@` will signal a new subarray. The string after `@` will be the sole element in the `@atsign` sub-sub-array. After this line will come any number of lines beginning with `=`, which will become the elements of the @EQsign sub-sub-array. Thus, in the real code, the subarrays will be initialized each time we come to a line like `@hrdl:raw_:in:__:`. And at each line like `=\.(((tex)|(txt))|((TEX)|(TXT)))`, another element will be pushed onto `@EQsign`.

But the previous two paragraphs do not bear on my question.
My question here is how to extract the array that corresponds to any index from 0 to `(scalar @BIG) -1)`. For instance, if I specify index 1, I want `@extracted_subarray` to have content and structure identical to the content and structure of the `@tmparray` that was built at iteration 1. In the example below, this means the `@tmparray` that existed in the 2nd block.

And I want `@extracted_subarray` and `@BIG` to exist independently of each other. Neither should be a mere pointer or reference to the other. Thus, if subsequently either `@tmparray` or `@BIG` is changed, I want the other array not to be affected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); #https://perlmaven.com/hash-of-arrays
select(STDERR);

my @BIG;

{
    my @tmparray;
    my @atsign;
    my @EQsign;
    push @atsign, 'hrdl:raw_:in:__:';
    push @EQsign, ( '\.(((tex)|(txt))|((TEX)|(TXT)))' );
    push @tmparray, [@atsign];
    push @tmparray, [@EQsign];
    push @BIG, [@tmparray];
}

{
    my @tmparray;
    my @atsign;
    my @EQsign;
    push @atsign, 'hrdl:raw_:EX:__:i';
    push @EQsign, ( 'bad words', 'bad\s*word' );
    push @EQsign, ( 'forbidden', );
    push @tmparray, [@atsign];
    push @tmparray, [@EQsign];
    push @BIG, [@tmparray];
}
print "BIG=\n"; print Dumper \@BIG;
my @extracted_subarray;
@extracted_subarray = pop @BIG;
print "extracted_subarray=\n"; print Dumper \@extracted_subarray;
```

Comment: Re "*The string after @ will be the sole element in the @atsign sub-sub-array.*", That makes no sense. There's no point in making an array that will always have exactly one element.

Comment: Re "*My practical application will not have hard-coded data elements like that. I will be iterating through a text file with individual lines for the individual elements of the array, and building the array from the text file.*", Still not an excuse for using `[@a]` instead of `\@a`. What I said in my answer stands.

Answer (score 3):

`@BIG` contains references to arrays. You can get one of those references as follows:

```perl
my $sub_array = $BIG[0];
```

Then, you can do stuff like `for (@$sub_array)`, `$sub_array->[0]`, etc. See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

---

Remember that `$BIG[0]` is just a reference to an array since you can't put arrays in arrays. To copy the reference array, you can use

```perl
my @shallow_copy_of_sub_array = @{ $BIG[0] };
```

Will you made a copy of the array referenced by `$BIG[0]` (`@tmparray`), the elements that array are also references, so `@shallow_copy_of_sub_array` and `@BIG` aren't fully independent. For example, changing `$shallow_copy_of_sub_array[0][0]` will effect `@BIG`.  To address that, we could use

```perl
my $copy = [
   [ $BIG[0][0] ],
   [ $BIG[0][1] ],
];
```

Or we could just copy all referenced variables, all the way down. This is called making a deep copy.

```perl
use Storable qw( dclone );

my $deep_copy = dclone($BIG[0]);
```

or

```perl
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( encode_json decode_json );

my $deep_copy = decode_json(encode_json($BIG[0]));
```

---

By the way,

```perl
{
    my @tmparray;
    my @atsign;
    my @EQsign;
    push @atsign, 'hrdl:raw_:in:__:';
    push @EQsign, ( '\.(((tex)|(txt))|((TEX)|(TXT)))' );
    push @tmparray, [@atsign];
    push @tmparray, [@EQsign];
    push @BIG, [@tmparray];
}
```

is wasteful. You are making copies of arrays for nothing. (`[ @atsign ]` is more or less equivalent to `my @anon = @atsign; \@anon`.) Fixed:

```perl
{
    my @tmparray;
    my @atsign;
    my @EQsign;
    push @atsign, 'hrdl:raw_:in:__:';
    push @EQsign, ( '\.(((tex)|(txt))|((TEX)|(TXT)))' );
    push @tmparray, \@atsign;
    push @tmparray, \@EQsign;
    push @BIG, \@tmparray;
}
```

It's still needlessly verbose, hindering readability. Fixed:

```perl
{
    my @atsign = 'hrdl:raw_:in:__:';
    my @EQsign = ( '\.(((tex)|(txt))|((TEX)|(TXT)))' );
    push @BIG, [ \@atsign, \@EQsign ];
}
```

You could even use

```perl
push @BIG, [
    [ 'hrdl:raw_:in:__:' ],
    [ '\.(((tex)|(txt))|((TEX)|(TXT)))' ],
];
```

That's sohhhh much clearer.

Comment: Changed answer to account for changed question.